# Accessing a Sails controller from a spawned process

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js, bootstrapping

I'm trying to spawn a background service upon Sails' lift.
Here's what I've come up with so far :

`config/bootstrap.js` :

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {

    sails.on('lifted', function() {
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        var worker = spawn('node', ['./worker.js']);
    });

    cb();

};
```

`worker.js`:

```
var sails = require('sails');

sails.controllers.MyController.myFunction(null, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I lift Sails, I get the following error : `Cannot read property 'MyController' of undefined`.

I tried without the `require('sails')` and without the `sails.controllers` in front of my controller's name, but then it throws me `MyController is not defined`.

Any idea why I can't access my controller from the bootstrap function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load or lift the Sails app in order to be able to access controllers, models, etc.  See [`sails.load()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/application/sails-load) and [`sails.lift()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/application/sails-lift) for more details.  So it'd be something like:

```
var sails = require('sails');
sails.load(function(err, sails) {
   if (err) {
     // handle error and exit process
   }
   // sails is now fully loaded
   sails.controllers.my.myFunction(null, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Side note, it's also weird to run controller code outside of the context of a request.  You probably should refactor that code into a [service](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/services) instead.  And as @elssar notes above, controller identities are lowercased and the "controller" part is removed.

Comment: You're right. After some research I realised I had misinterpreted what `spawn` is meant to achieve. It creates a completely independant process which thus cannot access any controller, model or anything from Sails' master process.
It's a shame though, I would be great to be able to create a kind of sub-process inside Sails and watch its output asynchronously like `spawn` allows to.
I guess I'm going to stick with a classic service but considering the nature of my application, it's a bit unadapted.

Comment: You can use `.fork()` to spawn a child process that has a communication channel for sending/receiving messages from the parent.  But I doubt you'd achieve what you were looking for this way.  Workers are generally used for long-running processes that would otherwise block the Node thread from handling events (like requests); if you called parent code from inside a child process then you'd still be blocking the parent thread.  If all you need is some state info from the parent, you could pass it down as command-line arguments to the worker.